# Can't paste text with line break into mobaxterm

Tags: mobaxterm

When I try to copy and paste text with line break into mobaxterm terminal, it fails and pastes nothing, it even clears my clipboard after failure. If I delete the line break in copied text, it works fine. I'm using windows 10, mobaxterm version is v23.0 Build 5042

For example, if I copy(note the extra line):

```
this is an example
```

And press `CTRL+V` into mobaxterm terminal, I only got:

```
username:~/tmp$
username:~/tmp$
```

It seems as if only the line break is copied, and my clipboard is cleared after doing this.
If I copy:

```
this is an example
```

And press `CTRL+V` into mobaxterm terminal, everything works fine:

```
username:~/tmp$
username:~/tmp$ this is an example
```

Comment: Example would help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta I edited my problem and tried to describe it in text, hope it makes my problem more clear